Interpretation of ARIMAX residuals
Plotted a seasonal ARIMAX model where I took one difference and one seasonal difference, am unsure of how do I interpret the residuals output below. The resultant model is ARIMA(2,1,2)(2,1,0)[12] where it passes the Ljung Box test.
I understand that it is meant to look like white noise which I observe to some extent with the ARIMA errors. However, what does the pattern of the Regression Errors here indicate?


Did you decide on the model parameters yourself, or did you use some flavor of auto-arima?

@StevenGubkin the model was generated with auto-arima

You can write the fitted model for $y_t$ in terms of previous observations and innovations by reading off your coefficients and following this process, where $B$ is the lag operator.
